# How to do a web scraping using Puppeteer and publish it?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, web-hosting

I would like to do a web-scraping using Puppeteer. It would be to obtain data from an external URL when the user clicks a button within my application. My application would have to visit an external URL, fill out a form, click on a button, get the data returned and display it to the user within my application. It is an internal project, at first, a small project.

I wrote a **test code to use Puppeteer** using the website:
https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

Worked perfectly. Great!

1. However, I was **unable to get my code to run on my domain** with **shared hosting on Locaweb**. It seems to me that I depend on changes on the server to be able to run Puppeteer, is that right?
2. Is there a **free place** where I can host my code and run with **Puppeteer** like I did at https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/?
   If you don't have a free option to suggest, could you suggest a low cost option that works?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure this is the right place for such recommandations. You could use a free heroku account or one of its alternative.

Comment: Thank you Alice. So, as I can tell, I'm having trouble publishing a code using Puppeteer and accessing the result of this code just by accessing any url - name.any-place.com. So, I would call that URL from within my application and I would get the desired result.
Would you have any steps to do this? Since the main code I already tested using https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. You would need to create a simple expressjs api.
2. Host the api somewhere (there are thousands of vps and cloud hosting providers like digitalocean/linode etc.)
3. Access that rest api using frontend (typically an ajax call)

There is indeed some free services, but they would be a bit more complex. You would need to learn about some serverless functions. Try searching for,

- AWS lambda
- Netlify functions
- Firebase functions
- Google cloud functions
- Google cloud run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers Md. Abu Taher.

Is there anything simple like that?

1. Enter the code at: https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/
2. Run to see if it runs as expected.
3. Copy the code and save it as code.js
4. Use the http: // code
   some-name.any-things.com / project / code.js and get the same test result done at https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/ in a string or inside any html.

Sorry, I have no experience in this part. Any explanation of the details is welcome.